# Using string in a class c++ outputs error

Tags: c++, string, class

I want to create a C++ class that uses the string library. Here is my source code:

test.h:

```
#include <string>


class info {
public:
    // constructor
    info (string first_name, string last_name, int age);
    // deconstructor
    ~info ();



private:
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
    int age;

};
```

And here is my header assist file: test.cpp

```
#include <string>
#include "test.h"


info::info (string first_name, string last_name, int age) {
    this->first_name = first_name;
    this->last_name = last_name;
    this->age = age;

}
info::~info () {
}
```

However it gives me **syntax error: identifier "string" is undefined**

Why is that? I am kinda a noobie to C++ Data Structures

Also, I am compiling this is Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Just use fully qualified name, `std::string` everywhere you use `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `std::` before `string` as you are using a *qualified name* (an identifier in the namespace `std`).

For example, you constructor should look like this:

```
info (std::string const& first_name, std::string const& last_name, int age);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend use `using` especially in header

Comment: Having using-statements in headers are bad since you expose the type in all files including that header.

Comment: I've corrected the question. I am using <string> instead of <string.h> but I still get the error, however I will try.

Comment: @DragosRizescu Use `std::string` not simply `string`.

Comment: It works, I have no idea tho why I have to use 'using std::string;', however I'll go warm up the books. Thanks!

Comment: @DragosRizescu `string` is an identifier defined within the namespace called `std`. We use the prefix `std::` when we want to looking through that namespace for the identifier. If you had `using namespace std` that would bring the identifiers from the `std` namespace into the global scope, so you would only have to use `string`. But don't do this, there are reasons why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @DragosRizescu Can you consider accepting my answer if it helped.

Comment: You must be joking? Passing strings by value?!

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk haha. Just realized that. Allow me to edit.